# Downloading an imgur image on Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to download an image from an incoming share intent that's a url String... it works fine for all other cases (that I've tried) except for those that come from imgur. All I end up with is this:

[image: imgur error]

Does anyone have any ideas what might be the cause?

The code that I'm using to download the file is this:

```
// Got this here: http://wininterview.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/download-file-in-android-from-remote.html
public static void downloadFile( String url, String destination ) {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        File file = new File(destination);

        URLConnection ucon = u.openConnection();
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The destination I'm downloading to is `this.getCacheDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName`

Before anyone tries to recommend using the imgur API, I'd prefer to try find a way around that since the incoming intent can be a url to an image from anywhere.

Edit: I've tried downloading the same file url using curl from the command line and it worked just fine.

Edit: Interestingly enough, if I do `u.openConnection().getContentLength()` it gives me `503` already so I can't even spoof request headers (which I also tried).

Comment: This doesn't directly pertain to your imgur issue but I highly recommend Square's [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for image loading

Comment: Can you give a sample URL that your app is failing to download?

Comment: Have you tried the image url in you browser?!

Comment: Here's an example of one, and yes it works in the browser on my desktop as well as on the browser on the phone: http://i.imgur.com/5O3dwAM.gif

Comment: @vmagro: I did try Picasso, but I wasn't quite sure how to get the file output to disk. Especially problematic is that the file (in this case) is an animated gif which I'm not sure that Picasso can handle.

Comment: As far as saving it to the disk you can implement the `Target` interface in Picasso to save the image Picasso downloaded.

Comment: @vmagro: Thanks! I may just give that a try... not sure how Picasso handles animated gifs though, but there's just one way to find out :P

Comment: @vmagro: Yeah, that's a no-go since Picasso only gives you a Bitmap which only has static image formats: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I was calling `.toLowerCase()` on the image url at some point and imgur's urls are very much case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a site that rejected requests without the user-agent string.
I had to add

```
private static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; GT-I9000 Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
```

to the request:

```
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri[0]);
            request.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

I was not using URLConnection, but on the server side there should be no difference.
If you want, I can post the code that once worked. OTOH, I am *not* sure if it is the cause of the problem.

PS I have also seen sites that required the `-e` (`--referer`) switch in `curl`; without `-e` they retrieved an html with a link to .zip rather than the .zip itself.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried setting the user agent string, but like I mentioned in my second edit, it didn't work since I can only set it after I open the connection at which point the content length is already wrong. I'll give your `HttpGet` method a go though... thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but let me give this a go first and I'll let you know if I get stuck.

Comment: I gave this a go with that UA string you gave, but still no luck :/ Oh, and the `referer` isn't required btw... it works in my browser without it.